# ElasticSearch aggregations - sorting values

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

In this sample I have some cars with an unknown number of facets on them.

When doing aggregations I would like the values in the aggregations to be sorted alphabetically. However, some of the facets are integers, and that will produce these aggregations

```
Color
 blue (2)
 red (1)

Top speed
 100 (1)
 120 (1)
 90 (1)

Year
 2015 (1)
```

As you can see the topspeed facet is sorted wrong - 90 should be first.

**Sample data**

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "displayname" :{"type": "string"}, 
        "facets": {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "name":     { "type": "string"  },
            "value":    { "type": "string"  },
            "datatype": { "type": "string"  }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



PUT /my_index/product/1
{
  "displayname": "HONDA",
  "facets": [
    {
      "name": "topspeed",
      "value": "100",
      "datatype": "integer"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "value": "Blue",
      "datatype": "string"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /my_index/product/2
{
  "displayname": "WV",
  "facets": [
    {
      "name": "topspeed",
      "value": "90",
      "datatype": "integer"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "value": "Red",
      "datatype": "string"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /my_index/product/3
{
  "displayname": "FORD",
  "facets": [
    {
      "name": "topspeed",
      "value": "120",
      "datatype": "integer"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "value": "Blue",
      "datatype": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "year",
      "value": "2015",
      "datatype": "integer"
    }
  ]
}

GET my_index/product/1

GET /my_index/product/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
   "aggs": {
    "facets": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "facets"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_facets": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "facets.name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "facet_value": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "facets.value",
                "size": 0,
                "order": {
                  "_term": "asc"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see each facet has a datatype (integer or string).

Any ideas how I can get the sorting of values to be like this:

```
Color
 blue (2)
 red (1)

Top speed
 90(1)     
 100 (1)
 120 (1)

Year
 2015 (1)
```

I've played around with adding a new field to the facet "sortable_value" where i pad the integer values like this "00000000090" at index time. But could not get the aggregations to work.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

That's an uncommon way of representing your data.

I'd suggest changing your data structure to the following

`{
  "displayname": "FORD",
  "facets": {
     "topspeed": 120,
     "color": "Blue",
     "year": 2015
   }
}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The product catalog is very diverse and the number of different facets (color,year, topspeed) is > 1000. The main problem is that we don't know the facets we can encounter

Comment: Then I suggest you specify the type for as many facets as possible in your mapping and leave the rest to `elasticsearch`. As long as your facets have different names, which they do i suppose, `elasticsearch` will assign an automatic type to any new field that hasn't appeared before based on the first field value. And this automatically assigned type usually makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I could easily add all the facets with individual mappings including the correct data type. But how could I then make an aggregation that targets all my facets?